# Applying datatables in jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables

I have a page where i use jqueryui dialog with datatables. When a button is clicked, the dialog opens and shows the table contents. Without datatables, the dialog performs as expected. But I couldn't get the expected result when datatables is applied to the table. So my question is, what is the best way to do this?

the dialog html:

```
<div id="customerDialog">
  <input type="button" id="selectCustomer" name="selectCustomer" value="Select" /> 
  <table id="custTable">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" id="custId" name="custId" value="0" /></td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>ye</td>
        <td>z@x.y</td>
        <td>000000000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" id="custId" name="custId" value="1" /></td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>ye</td>
        <td>z@x.y</td>
        <td>000000000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" id="custId" name="custId" value="2" /></td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>ye</td>
        <td>z@x.y</td>
        <td>000000000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" id="custId" name="custId" value="3" /></td> 
        <td>x</td>
        <td>ye</td>
        <td>z@x.y</td>
        <td>000000000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" id="custId" name="custId" value="4" /></td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>ye</td>
        <td>z@x.y</td>
        <td>000000000</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customerDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Customers",
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        modal: true,
        width: 500
    });

    $('#custTable').dataTable({
        bJQueryUI: true
    });

    $('#selectCustomer').click(function() {
        var target = $(this);
        $('#customerDialog').dialog("open");
        $('#customerDialog').dialog("widget").position({
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left bottom',
            of: target
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the expected result"? Does the dialog not open? Or what?

Comment: yes, the dialog opens, but datatables is not applied and i see a plain html table

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code is correct and in fact it works.

[image: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/CuvkR/]

Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/CuvkR/

```
$('#customerDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Customers",
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode",
    modal: true,
    width: 500
});

$('#custTable').dataTable({
    bJQueryUI: true
});

$('#selectCustomer').click(function() {
    var target = $(this);
    $('#customerDialog').dialog("open");
    $('#customerDialog').dialog("widget").position({
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left bottom',
        of: target
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. It works in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in my app. Could it be some url / path mapping issue or something? I am using spring mvc with jsp and apache tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same technologies as you do with heavy use of javascript. In such cases as you are describing the usual problem is that the DOM element does not exist at the time you initialized the plugin (datatables in this case).

Are loading the contents of the dialog via an AJAX call? It doesn't appear so, but you may be simplifying the code for us.

If so, then you need to use a custom event like this inside your ready() function

```
    $(document).on('datatable_loaded', function() {
        $('#custTable').dataTable({
            bJQueryUI: true
        });
    });
```

And in your AJAX success callback do this

```
    $(document).trigger('datatable_loaded');
```

In this example 'datatable_loaded' is an arbitrary string that you throw and catch yourself. If you are not using AJAX to load the dialog contents then this approach will not help you because the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I am not using ajax to pull the data. When the page loads initially it comes with the data and the table is populated by then. Is there any other way to trigger the datatable_reloaded event??

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer. There is no 'datatable_loaded' event in the datatable plugin. It is custom. It looks like your problem is elsewhere. Are you using Firebug to see if there are javascript errors?